# Flex custom toggleswitch not working in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, toggle

I have a custom Flex Toggleswitch component that changes the text values of the switch.

```
    package skins
{
    import spark.skins.mobile.ToggleSwitchSkin;

    public class MyToggleSwitchSkin extends ToggleSwitchSkin
    {
        public function MyToggleSwitchSkin()
        {
            super();
            selectedLabel="Serviceable";
            unselectedLabel="Fault";

        }
    }
}
```

If I add the control using the MXML tag, it works fine. However, when I add the component using action script, it does not.

```
import skins.MyToggleSwitchSkin;
public function addToggle():void {
   var myCustomToggle:MyToggleSwitchSkin = new MyToggleSwitchSkin();
   hgroup.addElement(myCustomToggle);
}
```

The control dsiplays but will not activate.

Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: What you've implemented is a custom ToggleSwitch-SKIN, not a custom ToggleSwitch. Try a subclass of ToggleSwitch instead.

Comment: I have an extension to the ToggleSwitch class in the Apache Flex repository that allows you to change these values using properties on the class instead of a custom skin.  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/flex/whiteboard/jhouser/ToggleSwitchAlternate/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your MXML Code, it's tough to compare your two approaches, but I believe @al_Birdy addressed the problem.  You've created a custom ToggleSwitchSkin; not a custom ToggleSwitch.

Modify your addToggle() method like this:

```
public function addToggle():void {
   var myCustomToggle:MyToggleSwitch = new MyToggleSwitch();
   myCustomToggle.setStyle('skinClass',skins.MyToggleSwitchSkin);
   hgroup.addElement(myCustomToggle);
}
```

I suspect you'll have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, still working to get over my rookie stage.